# Can you make columns optional for SQL Insert Row in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am using the Logic App designer on Azure. Added "*SQL Azure - Insert Row*" as an Action, it prompts me to insert values for the columns but all the columns are marked as required and it doesn't save the changes/sequence if a value is not entered there.

Is there anyway of bypassing this or making the columns optional?

Comment: i added more info to my answer with an illustration of the steps i took to resolve this. hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this previously, there was no way to make the columns optional but i figured a workaround. 
First, in the designer put any value, then open *Code view* and look for the columns you don't need and just delete it from the JSON schema and hit save :) 
that should do it for you, but next time you open in designer and try to edit you have to do this again.
let me know if it helps

***Edited***

I added a screenshot of the steps that i made while trying to replicate this. (note that your database schema should handle these null values for the columns, in my case the `Guid` had a default value of `newid()` and the other column allowed nulls). You always pass null to the columns, not passing values at all might make sense for columns that has values computed or has default values (like `newid()` uniqueidentifier or `getdate()` for created/modified time)

[image]

Comment: Thanks... it seems odd that it forces you to update all the fields in a table for an Update. I just want to change certain fields and not touch any of the existing data